# Python multiprocessing Queue broken after worker kill

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I made a program to simulate heavy mail management by using python multiprocessing Pool and Queue :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue
import time
import uuid
import os


NB_WORKERS = 3
NB_MAILS_PER_5_SECONDS = 2
MAIL_MANAGEMENT_DURATION_SECONDS = 1


def list_new_mails_id():
    for i in range(NB_MAILS_PER_5_SECONDS):
        # fake mailbox msg list
        yield str(uuid.uuid1())


def mail_worker(msg_ids):
    pid = os.getpid()
    print(f"Starting worker PID = {pid} and queue={msg_ids} queue size={msg_ids.qsize()} ...")
    while True:
        print(f"[{pid}] Waiting a mail to manage...")
        msg_id = msg_ids.get()
        print(f"[{pid}] managing mail msg_id = {msg_id} ...")
        # here should read mail msg_id and remove it from mailbox when finish
        print(f"[{pid}] --> fake duration of {MAIL_MANAGEMENT_DURATION_SECONDS}s")
        time.sleep(MAIL_MANAGEMENT_DURATION_SECONDS)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    msg_id_queue = Queue()

    with Pool(NB_WORKERS, mail_worker, (msg_id_queue,)) as p:
        while True:            
            for msg_id in list_new_mails_id():
                msg_id_queue.put(msg_id)
            print("\nWaiting for new mails to come...\n")
            time.sleep(5)
```

The program puts some message ids in a queue which are read by workers.
Workers are started and initialized with the same Queue object.
It works well.

To know how tolerant is the python `Pool()` and to know if tasks processing can continue despite a worker death because of some temporary memory issues for example, I killed a worker :

The `Pool()` re-create automatically the worker(s) and initilize it(them) with the same Queue object than before but the workers are not able anymore to get items in the queue : it is stuck on `msg_ids.get()` : why ?

I am using ubuntu 22.04 LTS and python 3.10.4

Comment: I do not think as there is no use of a Queue in the code you highlight

Comment: [Further down the issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/96062#issuecomment-1415596792) there's also a `Queue` involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must say that I find something very unusual in your code. Contrary to what you say, function `mail_worker` is *not* a "worker" function, i.e. a function that handles tasks that have been submitted to the pool, since in your code *no tasks* are being submitted to the pool.

`mail_worker` is a *pool initializer* meant to be executed once to initialize each pool process and from that point on you would submit tasks to the pool using a method like `map` or `apply_async`. But your initializer function never actually terminates.

Given that you are concerned about a process dying (an Exception or explicitly being killed -- but why?), you should also be concerned about losing a submitted "task" the process was working on. For this using an explicit task queue with `multiprocessing.Process` instances can offer a solution. Your process worker function would attempt to handle any exceptions and if it was in the middle of processing a task and had not completed it, it could re-queue the task before ending. You could even handle a SIGTERM signal sent to it (at least on Linux).

In the following demo a couple of processes are killed by sending a SIGTERM signal. The program only places 10 messages on the task queue so that it will eventually complete and all 10 messages do get processed.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time
import uuid
import os
import signal

NB_WORKERS = 3
NB_MAILS_PER_5_SECONDS = 2
MAIL_MANAGEMENT_DURATION_SECONDS = 1

class StopSentinel:
    pass

def list_new_mails_id():
    for i in range(NB_MAILS_PER_5_SECONDS):
        # fake mailbox msg list
        yield str(uuid.uuid1())

def mail_worker(msg_ids):

    def handle_termination():
        print(f'pid {pid} is terminating.')
        if msg_id is not None:
            # Put back on queue:
            msg_ids.put(msg_id)

    msg_id = None
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handle_termination)
    # Handle any other signals

    pid = os.getpid()
    print(f"Starting worker PID = {pid} and queue={msg_ids} queue size={msg_ids.qsize()} ...")
    try:
        while True:
            # prevent lost messages by preventing the main
            print(f"[{pid}] Waiting a mail to manage...")
            msg_id = msg_ids.get()
            if isinstance(msg_id, StopSentinel):
                break
            print(f"[{pid}] managing mail msg_id = {msg_id} ...")
            msg_id = None # show this has been processed
            # here should read mail msg_id and remove it from mailbox when finish
            print(f"[{pid}] --> fake duration of {MAIL_MANAGEMENT_DURATION_SECONDS}s")
            time.sleep(MAIL_MANAGEMENT_DURATION_SECONDS)
    except Exception:
        handle_termination()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    msg_id_queue = Queue()
    processes = [Process(target=mail_worker, args=(msg_id_queue,)) for i in range(NB_WORKERS)]
    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    for iteration_number in range(5): # so we eventually terminate
        for msg_id in list_new_mails_id():
            msg_id_queue.put(msg_id)
        print("\nWaiting for new mails to come...\n")
        time.sleep(5)
        # Kill some processes from time to time
        if iteration_number == 1:
            # Kill the first process
            print('terminating process 0')
            os.kill(processes[0].pid, signal.SIGTERM)
        elif iteration_number == 2:
            # Kill the first process
            print('terminating process 1')
            os.kill(processes[1].pid, signal.SIGTERM)

    # Put enough stop sentinels in the queue (extras are okay)
    stop_sentinel = StopSentinel()
    for _ in range(NB_WORKERS):
        msg_id_queue.put(stop_sentinel)
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
    print('Done!')
```

Prints:

```None
Starting worker PID = 35 and queue=<multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x7fd318b18fd0> queue size=0 ...
[35] Waiting a mail to manage...
Starting worker PID = 36 and queue=<multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x7fd318b18fd0> queue size=0 ...
[36] Waiting a mail to manage...
Starting worker PID = 37 and queue=<multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x7fd318b18fd0> queue size=0 ...
[37] Waiting a mail to manage...

Waiting for new mails to come...
[35] managing mail msg_id = c9d4b5dd-c105-11ed-9fe7-00155d5aa9bc ...
[35] --> fake duration of 1s

[36] managing mail msg_id = c9d55dab-c105-11ed-885b-00155d5aa9bc ...
[36] --> fake duration of 1s
[35] Waiting a mail to manage...
[36] Waiting a mail to manage...

Waiting for new mails to come...

[37] managing mail msg_id = ccd12a4c-c105-11ed-ab69-00155d5aa9bc ...
[37] --> fake duration of 1s
[36] managing mail msg_id = ccd12e18-c105-11ed-9702-00155d5aa9bc ...
[36] --> fake duration of 1s
[36] Waiting a mail to manage...
[37] Waiting a mail to manage...
terminating process 0
pid 35 is terminating.

Waiting for new mails to come...

[37] managing mail msg_id = cfccf70d-c105-11ed-bffe-00155d5aa9bc ...
[37] --> fake duration of 1s
[36] managing mail msg_id = cfccfb8e-c105-11ed-b879-00155d5aa9bc ...
[36] --> fake duration of 1s
[36] Waiting a mail to manage...
[37] Waiting a mail to manage...
terminating process 1
pid 36 is terminating.

Waiting for new mails to come...

[37] managing mail msg_id = d2c8d578-c105-11ed-8964-00155d5aa9bc ...
[37] --> fake duration of 1s
[37] Waiting a mail to manage...
[37] managing mail msg_id = d2c8e72e-c105-11ed-9181-00155d5aa9bc ...
[37] --> fake duration of 1s
[37] Waiting a mail to manage...

Waiting for new mails to come...

[37] managing mail msg_id = d5c4c7ea-c105-11ed-9edc-00155d5aa9bc ...
[37] --> fake duration of 1s
[37] Waiting a mail to manage...
[37] managing mail msg_id = d5c4d781-c105-11ed-9195-00155d5aa9bc ...
[37] --> fake duration of 1s
[37] Waiting a mail to manage...
Done!
```

Comment: You are right I was not using `Pool` the right way : I will stop using `Queue` but just `apply_async()`

Comment: I see that you just posted an answer of your own and it seems that you want to have the pool restart a new process after you have killed one, which implies a deliberate act, but did not want to have a new process take the place of the old one. I even mentioned in my answer that I did not understand why you would want to kill a process -- **you will lose a submitted "task"**. In the end your question was not worded very clearly.

Comment: I wanted to kill a worker to know how tolerant is the python `Pool()` and to know if tasks processing can continues despite some temporary memory issues for example. Finally, I retested my new solution and yours again, both cannot all the time survive : workers are re-created, but no more tasks are processed. At least, the `print()` are not displayed anymore.

Comment: Are you saying that if you run my code you do not get the same result? See [this demo](https://ideone.com/9Q6u4q), where I have reduced the sleep times because there is a 5 second timeout limit.

Comment: Yes, if I run your code and if I kill manually on linux terminal one worker process, the tasks processing is stuck despite the remaining workers are still runing. I am using ubuntu 22.04 LTS and python 3.10.4

Comment: Yes. But I mistakenly thought you were killing it using my "cooperative killing method".  See updated answer.

Comment: It is now good with your SIGTERM handler. A big tank you !

Answer (score 0):

Finally the solution was to not use `Queue` but simply `apply_async()` (`Pool` is using its own SimpleQueue internally). Unfortunately, the only solution to ensure tasks to be processed if a worker dies is ... to commit harakiri and let systemd restart the deamon...

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import os
import signal

NB_WORKERS = 3
NB_MAILS_PER_5_SECONDS = 2
MAIL_MANAGEMENT_DURATION_SECONDS = 1


def mail_worker_init():
    pid = os.getpid()
    print(f"Starting worker PID = {pid} ...", flush=True)


def mail_worker_task(msg_id):
    pid = os.getpid()
    print(f"[{pid}] managing mail msg_id = {msg_id} ...", flush=True)
    # here should read mail msg_id and remove it from mailbox when finish
    time.sleep(MAIL_MANAGEMENT_DURATION_SECONDS)
    print(f"[{pid}] --> msg_id = {msg_id} has been processed", flush=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    msg_id = 0
    with Pool(NB_WORKERS, mail_worker_init) as pool:
        pool_original_pids = [p.pid for p in pool._pool]
        print(f"Original PIDs = {pool_original_pids}")
        while True:
            pool_actual_pids = [p.pid for p in pool._pool]
            print(f"Actual PIDs = {pool_actual_pids}")
            # if pool processes changed, it mostly means tasks won't be
            # managed anymore (why ? this is the question)
            # So killing the whole deamon and let systemd restart it totally
            if pool_actual_pids != pool_original_pids:
                os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGKILL)
            for _ in range(NB_MAILS_PER_5_SECONDS):
                msg_id += 1
                pool.apply_async(mail_worker_task, (msg_id,))
            print("\nWaiting for new mails to come...\n", flush=True)
            time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the solution to not get stuck when a worker is killed is to declare a SIGTERM handler to exit properly. This is also the place to put back the killed task into the queue so it will be managed by another worker :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue
import time
import uuid
import os
import signal

NB_WORKERS = 3
NB_MAILS_PER_5_SECONDS = 2
MAIL_MANAGEMENT_DURATION_SECONDS = 1


def list_new_mails_id():
    for i in range(NB_MAILS_PER_5_SECONDS):
        # fake mailbox msg list
        yield str(uuid.uuid1())


def mail_worker(msg_ids):
    pid = os.getpid()
    msg_id = None

    def handle_termination(*args):
        print(f'pid {pid} is terminating.')
        if msg_id is not None:
            # Put back msg_id on queue before exiting:
            msg_ids.put(msg_id)
        exit()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handle_termination)

    print(f"Starting worker PID = {pid} and queue={msg_ids} queue size={msg_ids.qsize()} ...")
    while True:
        print(f"[{pid}] Waiting a mail to manage...")
        msg_id = msg_ids.get()
        print(f"[{pid}] managing mail msg_id = {msg_id} ...")
        # here should read mail msg_id and remove it from mailbox when finish
        time.sleep(MAIL_MANAGEMENT_DURATION_SECONDS)
        print(f"[{pid}] --> mail msg_id = {msg_id} processed")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    msg_id_queue = Queue()

    with Pool(NB_WORKERS, mail_worker, (msg_id_queue,)) as p:
        while True:            
            for msg_id in list_new_mails_id():
                msg_id_queue.put(msg_id)
            print("\nWaiting for new mails to come...\n")
            time.sleep(5)
```